# pyodbc not working when runing unicorn/fastapi

Tags: python, pyodbc, uvicorn

I have a fastAPI program that needs to use pyodbc to connect to SQL server. Please refer to the code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel
import json
import pyodbc
from datetime import date, datetime

app = FastAPI()
############## Setup SQL connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=192.168.1.x;'
                      'Database=test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

def check_exists_device(DevEUI):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM iotDevice WHERE devuid='{DevEUI}'")
    queryResult = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(queryResult) >0:
        print("Exist device")
    else:
        print("Not Exist device")
```

When I run the program, it works well, the function check_exists_device works. But when I start the uvicorn on the terminal this command:

```
uvicorn webService:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7878 --reload
```

it shows the error

```
     File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 479, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\martin\PycharmProjects\pythonKafka\.\webService.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

Please help, I install and import pyodbc module already and when I run the program it works well, just when I start program by uvicorn, the error shows.

Comment: Please verify that the `pyodbc` package is installed by `pip list` command. If it is missing, install it. Another problem could be that you need to install an appropriate SQL driver before connection to the database.